# Make Excel Spreadsheet Fill Page when Printed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, printing

I am attempting to print a spreadsheet that automatically fills the page utilizing all space available. The amount of rows varies, but the columns do not. The reason is that people hand write in the space/empty boxes and I want them as big as possible while fitting everything on one page.

Portrait mode is preferred, and a simple solution would be better, but I am familiar with Macros.

Here is an example that I'd like to fill entire page.

[image: Example Table to Print]

Update: I can find how to "shrink"/Fit on 1 page, but generally everything fits on one page. I want it to expand to fill page + always fit on one page.

Update 2: I have set "Page Layout/Setup" to have "Width + Height" = 1 Page which seems to scale it a bit bigger, but there is still room at the bottom of the page that could be utilized. At this point I'd like to increase the size of the rows to fill up all space.

Update 3: I have succeeded in "manually" doing what I want, but I'd like a way to automate it for other users. At this point I'm thinking VBA might be the way to go.

How I manually accomplish my task:

```
Page Layout >> Gridlines >> Print #This shows page margins as dotted dashs
Page Layout >> Margins >> Narrow
Drag Columns to fit right-hand margin
Select Print Area >> Home >> Cells >> Format >> "Row Height" 
@ Row Height I have to "guess" then slowly "target" in on the correct #
which best utilizes the space for one page as I compare to the Print Gridlines on page.
```

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? Please have a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I'm not sure how that meta thread applies? I find myself to be very good at posting questions, can you tell me what I need to improve? I did add an "Update 2" with what I tried so far.